# How to reduce the spacing in boxplot between groups using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to reduce the spacing in boxplot between groups without changing the boxplot width. Most solutions online are to adjust the distance within a sub-group, but not between groups. Thanks a lot!

```
library("ggplot2")
data(iris)                           # Example data
iris_new <- iris
iris_new$new <- letters[1:2]

ggplot(iris_new, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = new)) +
       geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, I can't find an exact duplicate for this question, so will post an answer here in case no-one else can find a duplicate either.

The answer lies in *either* increasing the width of your boxes (the default is 0.75, so increasing to 1 might work well for you):

```r
ggplot(iris_new, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = new)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1)
```

[image]

*or* changing from the default `position_dodge2` to `position_dodge`, with an increase in the width of the dodge (again the default is 0.75, so we can try increasing this to 1)

```r
ggplot(iris_new, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = new)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks a lot for your help. Is it possible to keep the boxplot width and only reduce the spacing between groups?

Comment: That's what the second option does @YangYang..